# Flutter Issue: Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value

Tags: flutter, dart

I know, It is asked many time but none of the solution is working.

There is a bank list in first drop down, On bank selection an api is being called for branch in second drop down after selection of branch for first time it is working fine, When bank is changed again api is being called to get branch of respective bank that time issue is coming because already selected branch has value, I'm trying to clear previous selected value of branch and making list empty before populating branch. Issue is coming because branch area is same in other bank also but branch id is unique. when branch list is empty or not having same branch area that time there is no issue.

I tried to "overrried" method for comparing branch but not working

this is model class for branch.

```
class Branch {
  final int? bankId;
  final int? branchId;
  final String? ifscCode;
  final String? descriptionEn;
  final dynamic descriptionLl;
  
  Branch({
    this.bankId,
    this.branchId,
    this.ifscCode,
    this.descriptionEn,
    this.descriptionLl,
  });

  factory Branch.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Branch(
        bankId: json["bank_id"],
        branchId: json["branch_id"],
        ifscCode: json["ifsc_code"],
        descriptionEn: json["description_en"],
        descriptionLl: json["description_ll"],
      );
  
  @override
  String toString() {
    return descriptionEn.toString();
  }
  @override
  bool operator ==(dynamic other) {
    return other != null && branchId == other.branchId &&
        descriptionEn == other.descriptionEn;
  }
}
```

After getting state change of branch making previous selected branch null

```
else if (state is GetBranchSuccessState) {
            
            selectedBranch = null;
            ifsc = null;
            branchList=[];
            branchList = state.data.data!;

          }
```

Whenever choosing same bank as i firstly selected getting no issue it seems selected value is getting store?

My Widget

```
 BlocConsumer<InternalRegistrationBloc, InternalRegistrationState>(
        listener: (context, state) {
          if (state is GetBankSuccessState) {
            dismissProgress();
          } else if (state is GetBranchSuccessState) {
            dismissProgress();
          }
        },
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is GetBankSuccessState) {
            bankList = state.data.data!;
          } else if (state is GetBranchSuccessState) {
            selectedBranch = null;
            ifsc = null;
            branchList = [];
            branchList = state.data.data!;
          }
          return Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Form(
                key: _gformKey,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    QDropDownList(
                      title: 'Bank name',
                      dropdownList: bankList,
                      selectedItem: selectedBank,
                      isMandatory: isBankUser,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        selectedBank = value;
                        if (selectedBank != null) {
                          bloc.add(BranchEvent(selectedBank!.bankId!));
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                    QDropDownList(
                      title: 'Branch name',
                      dropdownList: branchList,
                      selectedItem: selectedBranch,
                      isMandatory: isBankUser,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        selectedBranch = value;
                        bloc.add(
                            SetIFSCCodeEvent(selectedBranch!.ifscCode!));
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
```

In Image, **bank of india** getting issue because branch list contain the same branch ares name as **Axis Bank** contain, It has no issue when i select **Bank of rajshthan** becuase it has no branch list. when selecting  **Axis Bank** bank getting no issue and getting old value.

Custom drop down

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class QDropDownList extends StatefulWidget {
  final ValueChanged<dynamic> onChanged;
  final List<dynamic> dropdownList;
  final dynamic selectedItem;
  final bool isTitleAbove;
  final String title;
  final bool isMandatory;
  final String dropDownHint;
  final Icon arrowIcon;

  const QDropDownList(
      {super.key,
      required this.onChanged,
      required this.dropdownList,
      required this.selectedItem,
      this.isTitleAbove = true,
      this.title = 'Title',
      this.isMandatory = true,
      this.dropDownHint = 'Select',
      this.arrowIcon = const Icon(
        Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
        size: 15,
      )});

  @override
  State<QDropDownList> createState() => _QDropDownListState();
}

class _QDropDownListState extends State<QDropDownList> {
  dynamic selectedItem;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    selectedItem = widget.selectedItem;
  }

  @override
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        widget.isTitleAbove
            ? Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
                child: RichText(
                  text: TextSpan(
                      text: widget.title,
                      style: Theme.of(context).inputDecorationTheme.labelStyle,
                      children: [
                        TextSpan(
                            text: widget.isMandatory ? ' *' : '',
                            style: Theme.of(context)
                                .inputDecorationTheme
                                .labelStyle
                                ?.copyWith(color: Colors.red))
                      ]),
                ),
              )
            : const SizedBox(),
        Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
            child: SizedBox(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: DropdownButtonFormField<dynamic>(
                value: selectedItem,
                icon: widget.arrowIcon,
                isDense: true,
                isExpanded: false,
                style: Theme.of(context).dropdownMenuTheme.textStyle,
                hint: Text(widget.dropDownHint,
                    style: Theme.of(context).dropdownMenuTheme.textStyle),
                // ignore: prefer_is_empty
                items:widget.dropdownList.length>0? widget.dropdownList.map((data) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem<dynamic>(
                    value: data,
                    child: Text(
                      data.toString(),
                      style: Theme.of(context).dropdownMenuTheme.textStyle,
                    ),
                  );
                }).toList():[],
                onChanged: (dynamic value) {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedItem = value;
                    widget.onChanged(value);
                    debugPrint('Drop down change ---> $selectedItem');
                  });
                },
                validator: (value) {
                  if (widget.isMandatory) {
                    return value == null ? 'Field required' : null;
                  } else {
                    return null;
                  }
                },
              ),
            )),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Does your widget refer to the same `selectedBranch` variable? I feel like that might not be the case here. Maybe it's helpful if you post the screen's full code

Comment: @Ivo updating full code of widget

Comment: @Ivo code update

Comment: hmm..  maybe the issue lies inside `QDropDownList` I don't know what it looks like but I can imagine it sets the `selectedItem` in the state only in the `initState` or something, meaning that when it changes later in the widget it doesn't work. Maybe could you show the code of `QDropDownList`?

Comment: @Ivo right, Dropdown is custom widget and selected item is getting change in initstate.

Comment: @Ivo not using any state management in custom class, Code added for custom class

Comment: yeah the way that's implemented causes the problem. I will write up an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in `QDropDownList`. The widget gets a `selectedValue` but its state has a separate `selectedValue`. This one is only set in the `initState`. Which means that later on when you set the `selectedValue` to `null` it will not be changed in its state because that only happens when it's first initialized in `initState` My suggestion is to completely remove the one from the state and rely on the widget's `selectedState`. So in all:

Remove these lines:

```
  dynamic selectedItem;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    selectedItem = widget.selectedItem;
  }
```

Change:

```
value: selectedItem,
```

to

```
value: widget.selectedItem,
```

And finally change

```
            onChanged: (dynamic value) {
              setState(() {
                selectedItem = value;
                widget.onChanged(value);
                debugPrint('Drop down change ---> $selectedItem');
              });
            },
```

to

```
            onChanged: (dynamic value) {
              setState(() {
                widget.onChanged(value);
                debugPrint('Drop down change ---> $selectedItem');
              });
            },
```

Note that you don't need to set a selected state here because the widgets `onChanged` will take care of that

Comment: Thanks working fine